# Accessing a system shared library on Android

Tags: android, system, shared, exif

How do I access a system library from my Android Java code?

I'm using Eclipse to develop my app and trying to load "libexif.so", which from DDMS I can see resides in /system/lib/

Basically, I'm extending the existing android.media.ExifInterface.java with some additional features I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use the NDK (Native Development Kit).

Comment: I don't need to write my own C code, just load an existing shared library. I'm happy with the native C functions in /system/lib/libexif.so, I just want to write my own version of android.media.ExifInterface. System.loadLibrary("exif") fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: So do I have to locate the C source of libexif.so, build it with a different name using the NDK and link it in to my Java project? I'm fine with this, just would have preferred linking to the existing .so